# WebGL: Texture appears as black

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a simple WebGL canvas, where I'm attempting to render a texture on a square. When working with textures as local files, all is fine. But when I try to load a texture from the web, I get a black canvas.

Please see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rLqEr/) for a demo. I have made the shaders and JavaScript very simple.

Comment: I don't know if it matters (it can'be judged by the fiddle), but make sure that the loading of your texture complies to the cross-domain access rules: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebGL/Cross-Domain_Textures

Comment: Yes, I've made sure to use Picasa (which does CORS) and to have the line `image.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';` to indicate that I'm using CORS.

Comment: There's no actual question here. You're far more likely to get results (and not have your post closed) if you ask a concrete question and place the relevant source or examples in the question itself, and not link to them externally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the texture parameters for non-power of 2 textures. Adding these 2 lines fixed the issue

```
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```

Comment: I've got these same declarations in my code, but it's still rendering non-pot textures as black. What else could one be missing?

Comment: did you set `gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.LINEAR);`?

Comment: I have `TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` set to `LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` and `TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` to `GL.LINEAR` Though I don't quite understand the min and mag filtering to effectively use them.

Comment: you can't use `LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR` without mips. https://webgl2fundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-3d-textures.html If you want help you'll need to ask new question  and post a minimal repo